# Rxswift operator share replay can not work?

Tags: ios, swift, system.reactive, rx-swift

what I need to do is, I have a lot network requests, and at a time backend will return a token expire error, all the requests will receive this error and they all should be hang up, at this time I need send a refresh token request. after refresh token request finish, all paused network request should relaunch with the new token.

now I use `retryWhen` operator to handle token expire error, and hang up network. I use `share replay` operator to send refresh token request only once.

```
networkReqeust.retryWhen({ (error: Observable<TokenError>)  in

                           error.flatMap{ error -> Observable<()> in
                               switch error {
                               case .TokenExpired:

                                return RefreshTokenObservable.share(replay: 1).flatMap({ (result) -> Observable<()> in
                                       switch result {

                                       case .RefreshSuccess:

                                           return Observable.empty()
                                       case .RefreshFailure:      
                                           throw error
                                       }
                                   })
                               }
                           }
                       })



let RefreshTokenObservable: Observable<TokenRefresh> = {

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession.init(configuration: config)
    let refreshTokenrequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

    return  session.rx.response(request: refreshTokenrequest).share(replay: 1).observeOn(MainScheduler.instance).flatMapLatest{ (data, response) -> Observable<TokenRefresh> in

        let responseModel = ResponseModel(data:response)
            if responseModel.status {
                return Observable.just(TokenRefresh.RefreshSuccess)
            } else {
                return Observable.just(TokenRefresh.RefreshFailure)
            }
        }.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
}()
```

now refresh token request still launch many times, where I did wrong. why `share replay`operator not work

Comment: The solution is here: https://medium.com/@danielt1263/retrying-a-network-request-despite-having-an-invalid-token-b8b89340d29

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RxSwift - Recursive Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555764/rxswift-recursive-observables)

Comment: @DanielT. ths, this is exactly what I need